# using malloc for double pointer

Tags: c, pointers

```
char **three = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*));
```

`char**`, the char pointer type is used. and `char**` means I'm dereferencing char pointer. and as for the `sizeof(char*)` I'm using the size of `char` pointer which is 8 byte.

Am I misunderstanding this?

Comment: `char **` means a pointer to a `char *`.

Comment: [don't cast malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: Your sentence is confusing, it's hard to tell what you understand about it.

Comment: Note: easier to code alternative: `three = malloc(sizeof *three);`

Answer (score 3):

So the code:

```
char **three = ( char** )malloc( sizeof( char* ) );
```

Allocates an array of pointers-to-char, but with only a single element.  The variable `three` is a pointer-to, a pointer-to a char. Much the same as:

```
char *three[1];
```

Normally (as @paxdiablo points out), it would be more usual to allocate a number of pointers:

```
int line_count = 66;
char **three = ( char** )malloc( line_count * sizeof( char* ) );
```

Once allocated, this can be used with array notation:

```
three[0] = "The Owl and the Pussy-cat went to sea";
three[1] = "In a beautiful pea-green boat,";
three[2] = "They took some honey, and plenty of money,";
three[3] = "Wrapped up in a five-pound note."
```

There's nothing particularly special about a `char**`, every C/C++ program gets one as its `argv`.

As a programmer, you don't really know that your pointer is *8* bytes, you know the pointer will be *some* size.  This is where the `sizeof( char* )` comes in. During compilation the compiler swaps this with the real value.  That way when the architecture is 16, 32 or 64 bit (or maybe 128 bit in the future), the code still compiles fine.

Answer (score 2):

Let's see if we can break this down:

```
char **three = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*));
[     1    ][5][  4   ][ 3  ] [    2      ]
```

1. Create a variable `three` of type `char **`, a pointer to a `char *` (often a "string" in C).
2. Use the size of a `char*` to pass to `malloc`.
3. Use `malloc` to allocate that many bytes.
4. Cast the return value from `malloc`, a `void*`, to `char**`.
5. Assign that value to `three`.

So in terms of where I think your misunderstanding lies:

- Do not cast the return value of `malloc` or `realloc` in C. C is perfectly capable of implicitly casting `void*` to other pointer types and doing it explicitly can hide certain subtle errors.
- There is no dereferencing going on here. The (unwise) cast is exactly that, telling the compiler you want to treat an expression of one type as if it was another type.
- You've actually allocated an array of `char*` variables and that array size is one. So, short of calling `realloc` on it at some point, its use is limited (unless you need it to survive the current scope, you're probably just better using a local variable rather than an allocated one-element array).